# Deleting a remote directory using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy a Ruby on Rails application to a server.  Everything is running up until the point when bundle install is called in which case I get the error "Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory."

This error is caused because there are some gems checked into the vendor/cache directory of the git repository that Capistrano is cloning from.  I understand the best approach would be to clean up the git repository but since that is not an option for me I would like to have Capistrano delete the vendor/cache directory on the remote server after the git clone but before the call to bundle.  I have run the steps manually and have found that by deleting the directory manually bundle executes correctly but I can't seem to figure out how to get Capistrano to perform the delete.

Here is the pertinent fragment from my deploy.rb file:

```
after "deploy:update_code" do
  run "rm -rf #{release_path}/vendor/cache"
end
after "deploy:update_code", "bundle:install"
```

And here is the command line output

```
executing `deploy:update_code'
executing locally: "git ls-remote my_git_repository HEAD"
command finished in xxxms
* executing "git clone [snipped for brevity]
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
** [my_server :: out] Error reading response length from authentication socket.
** [my_server :: out]
command finished in xxxms
* executing `deploy:finalize_update'
triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
* executing `bundle:install'
* executing "[snipped for brevity] bundle install [snipped for brevity]"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
** [out :: my_server] Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
** [out :: my_server] 
** [out :: my_server] Could not find gem-version in any of the sources
** [out :: my_server] 
command finished in xxxms
```

It does not look like `run "rm -rf #{release_path}/vendor/cache"` ever gets run.  Am I using the correct command?  Any other ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering whether it's an issue with the order the tasks are being run; perhaps try the following?

```
task :clean_vendor_cache do
  run "rm -rf #{release_path}/vendor/cache"
end
before "bundle:install", "clean_vendor_cache"
```